# Enhance react component with HOC

Tags: reactjs, components, high-order-component

I need to create a reusable Camera component, to do that I want to pass a custom record button and I need to attach to it extra functions or overwrite button text.

Here an example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hoc-ksjbf

I have created a hoc.js that takes custom component and try to overwrite text prop but I have this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I don't understand was wrong with it, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are passing a JSX literal (i.e. object) as a prop value to (*be passed to*) the higher order component versus a React component.

```
recordbutton={<Button text="Original Text" />}
```

## Solution

Pass a React component instead

```
<Camera recordbutton={(props) => <Button text="Original Text" {...props} />} />
```

or define and pass

```
const RecordButton = (props) => <Button text="Original Text" {...props} />;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Camera recordbutton={RecordButton} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

or pass the `Button` component directly

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Camera recordbutton={Button} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

So long as you are passing all props on through to the component then the HOC can inject/override prop values.

Update the HOC to spread the passed props in *before* providing the overrides, this is so the HOC can *actually* override them.

```
function alterText(Component) {
  return function (props) {
    return <Component {...props} text="new text"  />;
  };
}
```